# How Data Transfers differ on Smart Phones: Iphone vs. Android vs. Windows Phone

Tags: database, iphone, android, windows-phone-7

I am interested in how each individual smart phone is allowed to handle data transfers within a third-party app. I am interested in designing apps that allow customers to update, transfer, download, etc. data from their smart phone to their personal computer and vice-versa. (Ranging from just text, to XML, to a Relational Database)

I only have experience with the Ipod Touch before and one particular app that maintained all the data on an online server, so to update the data on your pc or iphone you had to go online, are there other ways to do it? Like bluetooth, wireless LAN, USB, etc? I believe Apple has certain policies on this in order to control the App Store and individual Iphones. I suppose each company has a particular policy on how an app is allowed to transfer data to another system, does anyone have a good understanding of this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iPhone, Apple only cares really if you are sending info about a Person or Device to an back end server. If you send personal info (name, phone number, etc), you have to let people know about it somewhere. That's just a policy they have. I think they also have some restriction on sending info about a particular device or its capabilities (OS version, display resolution, etc). Other than that I think most everything else is fair game.

For Android apps, there is no policy that I know of, but users will get warned when installing the app that it requires Internet access. But that's the case for many apps, so no worries.

To send data to a server from iPhone or Android phone it is pretty easy. To send data to a personal PC is harder since typically your PC won't be running any services to listen for connections from the App. So I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at with that part of the question.